# jQuery ifElse statement not running 'else' commands

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function im trying to write to make my sidebar sticky.

I have the following, that works fine in setting my div to position:fixed, only when I scroll back up the page, my div class isn't then changed to position:relative.

Can anybody spot obvious flaws in my syntax?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    divOffset = $('#sidebar').offset().top,
    dist = (divOffset - scrollTop);

if (dist > 50) {
    $('#sidebar').css({position:"relative",top:""});
} else if (dist < 50) {
    $('#sidebar').css({position:"fixed",top:"0px","margin-left":"730px"});
}
});
```

Comment: If `dist` *equals* 50 then it wouldn't fall into either of those cases (don't know if that's the issue; just an observation). Was that your intent?

Comment: thanks @eldarerathis I did have >= I'm just trying to debug it so my syntax is all a messy atm

Comment: Post some markup please

Comment: Use `console.log()` to find out what the value of "dist" is.

Comment: my distance remains unchanged when I log the value to console, 356.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an `if/else`. It's an `if/else if` with no default `else` condition. I imagine you'll want to cover the case where `dist` equals `50` by using a plain old `if/else`:

```
if (dist > 50) {
    $('#sidebar').css({position:"relative",top:""});
} else {
    $('#sidebar').css({position:"fixed",top:"0px","margin-left":"730px"});
}
```

There's no way one of those conditions won't execute (there are no syntax errors). You can use `alert` or `console.log` to determine for sure what parts of your script are being executed.

It sounds like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @sgroves, my distance remains unchanged when I log the value to console, 356.

Comment: that's correct; you're not changing `dist` after you calculate it. the problem appears to be elsewhere (maybe `top: ""`? that doesn't look right to me)